# sf::Music on Windows: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll: cannot open shared object file

Tags: c++, windows, sfml

I'm trying to use the SFML on Windows but when I use sf::Music, my application crash with the following error message:

```
 error while loading shared libraries: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm on Windows 10 1909 with the SFML 2.5.1.

Would someone please know how to fix that?

Comment: You will probably get more luck by asking on SFML github or forum. I can guess that the issue somewhere in the linking.

Comment: You need to install the Visual Studio 2015 C++ redistributable of the appropriate bitness.

Comment: It's already installed on my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end I found the answer to my question, I was missing openal32.dll next to my executable.